# recursive function for freeing memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm trying to write a recursive function that frees up the entire linked list. I'm still quite new to recursive functions so I'm not sure if I'm even doing this right. I ran valgrind to my code and I got back an error but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

```
==1156== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 3
==1156==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1156==    by 0x422454: main (destroy.c:24)
```

I believe the error lies somewhere in my code. Any help would be really nice. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

void destroy(node* list);

int main (void)
{
    node* list = NULL;
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    n->number = 1;
    n->next = NULL;
    list = n;
    n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    n->number = 2;
    n->next = NULL;
    list->next = n;
    n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    n->number = 3;
    n->next = NULL;
    list->next->next = n;

    destroy(list);
}

void destroy(node* list)
{
    if(list->next == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
    }
    else
    {
        return destroy(list->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Better if `destroy(node* list)` checks `list == NULL` before `list->anything`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only free'ing just one node that's at the end of the list. Because the "nodes" are not freed when the recursion unwinds.

You'd to rewrite it like:

```
void destroy(node* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return;
    destroy(list->next);
    free(list);
}
```

But IMO, recursion isn't necessary here. A simple loop might be a better choice:

```
void destroy(node* list)
{
    node* temp;

    while (list != NULL) {
        temp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Think of 1000's of nodes in the list. Why do you want "save" the nodes in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) for no good reason? It's both inefficient and dangerous (call stack could overflow).

Comment: Thank you for you help! I understand it better now

Comment: If this answer helped, [you may consider accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).